# Enable Doctrine 2 cache in a ZF2 project

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How to enable cache in a project working with Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2? and what cache exactly should be enabled the doctrine cache or the zend cache?

Here what i've tried but can't see any diference in the time execution added in the

> module\Application\config\module.config.php

```
 'doctrine.cache.my_memcache' => function ($sm) {
            $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
            $memcache = new \Memcache();
            $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
            $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
        return $cache;
      }, 


    'doctrine.cache.apc' => function ($sm){
            $apc = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
            return $apc;
    },



    // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'   => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'),
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ),
            )
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_defaults' => array(
                'metadata_cache'    => 'apc',
                'query_cache'       => 'apc',
                'result_cache'      => 'my_memcache',
            )
        )
    ),
```

any help or idea or explication is appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To reduce unnecessary headaches, always use `array` cache on development time and `memcached`, `redis` or `apc` when your application running on production environment.

You should put your factory definitions under the `service_manager` > `factories` key, not directly in the module configuration array.

Try this in your `module.config.php`:

```
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'metadata_cache' => 'mycache',
                'query_cache' => 'mycache',
                'result_cache' => 'mycache',
                'hydration_cache' => 'mycache',
            ]
        ],
    ],

    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
                $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
                $memcache = new \Memcache();
                $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
                $cache->setMemcache($memcache);

                return $cache;
            },
        ],
    ],
];
```

Also I strongly recommend moving factories to individual factory classes, always. This way, you'll have a more readable, maintainable and efficient application on production environment with the help of [merged configuration cache](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/config.advanced.html#system-configuration).

For example:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'doctrine.cache.mycache' => \App\Memcache\Factory::class // implement FactoryInterface
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Update for future readers after several years:**

I would highly recommend looking into [roave/psr-container-doctrine](https://github.com/Roave/psr-container-doctrine) 
before writing custom dedicated factories for various doctrine components such as entity manager, config or cache. As a contributor of the library I can say that it serves the purpose nicely for most of the use cases I needed so far. When you really need a specialized factory, you can either extend or compose or decorate factories provided and add your own logic on top it.

Comment: thanks for your reply ... i'll do it now , but can 'i have a question how do i know that the cache is working ?

Comment: You can try to grab from doctrine configuration in any service locator aware class, for example `$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.configuration.orm_default');` and `$cache = $config->getQueryCacheImpl();`

Comment: ok thanks i'll try it and come for the feed back ... thanks a lot.

Comment: that's all what i get using what you've suggest : Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache Object ( [memcache:Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache:private] => Memcache Object ( [connection] => Resource id #146 ) [namespace:Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider:private] => [namespaceVersion:Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider:private] => 1 ) 1

Comment: where files cache is saving ?

Comment: very naive question:  is this supposed to simply work automagically? some of the docs and comments that I see (e.g on Stack) seem to imply that it is. Or do you have to explicitly use the fetch|contains|save|delete API in your repository classes etc? the docs give some examples of that, too.

Comment: Yes, metadata cache, query cache and result cache utilized automatically by doctrine under the hood since it properly configured. All of these cache providers has good interfaces ($cache->save($key, $item, $ttl), $cache->has($key)) and of course you can also utilize them for your business-related data in different layers of your application.